# How to pass parameters between New and Create actions?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a parameter in my url when linking to the New action. I need this parameter in the create action. How do you do it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You may use a hidden field.

```
<input id="thing" type="hidden" value="<%= params[:thing] %>" />
```

Put that code in the *new* view.

Comment: Or if you prefer a Rails helper: `<%= hidden_field_tag 'thing', params[:thing] %>`

Comment: I noticed that you need to add `name` to `input`. It's helps to rails to add key to `params`. Just like this `<input name="document_id" type="hidden" value="<%= params[:document_id] %>" />`

Answer (score 3):

I've found that `<input type="hidden" name="modal" value="true" />` also works.

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stackoverflow! Can you please expand your answer a bit? It is not entirely clear how this helps asker

Comment: Similar to the answer given by Nerian my code also passes to the controller an extra param that can be accessed as params[:modal] if it is not in form or params[:object][:modal] if the line is in form_for object